# How to replace docker on Snappy?

Tags: ubuntu-core, docker

I just installed Snappy on my OdroidC++ board and would also like to use Docker 1.9. However, snappy offer Docker 1.6, which does not support important features.

Now, I would like to use precompiled Docker 1.9 files instead of the installed ones. But the new concept of Snappy does not allow to just edit files even as root.

So what can I do in order to replace the docker 1.6 available in snappy by a custom one?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, we only support docker 1.6, but we do have a newer version of docker on the roadmap for ubuntu core 16.04.

There may we some way we can make your snap working out with 1.6 in the mid-term? Do not hesitate to join us on irc (freenode) #snappy and ask around! :)

Comment: How to install docker in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS?

Comment: @Ashu, installing Docker on Ubuntu 14.04LTS is easy... Ubnt Core introduces a new security feature, which makes custom changes hard.

Comment: @didrocks, thank you. So there is no way to update to 1.9 before core 16.04?